# Secure way for sending Data to Amazon S3 with small fleet of RaspberryPi using Python and boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, raspberry-pi, cloud

For simple testing and prototyping, I've uploaded and downloaded to an S3 bucket using the nice boto3 package with access key id and secret access key - works fine.

Now I am thinking about a secure implementation for following use case:
I have a small fleet of RPI0 recording an image (around 5MB) and sending it to S3 bucket each 1h.

Shall I work with urls:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=912558&#912558

Or is generating a user and configuring policies with access key id and secret access key secure enough?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very complex subject. I highly recommend you look into using the [AWS IoT service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/what-is-aws-iot.html). The IoT service has features for [provisioning fleets of devices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-provision.html), [securing them](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/device-defender.html), and [giving them access to other AWS services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/authorizing-direct-aws.html) such as S3.